# Migrate user password hash

Tags: 8, migrations

We are migrating our old site from plain PHP to Drupal 8. Passwords are hashed with MD5 in the old site; I need to migrate them in Drupal.

I tried the following code, but it takes the password as plain text and calculates its SHA hash.

```
public function prepareRow(Row $row) {
    $password = $row->getSourceProperty('user_password');
    $hash = \Drupal::service('password')->hash($password);
    $row->setSourceProperty('user_password', $hash);
  }
```

This is the configuration file.

```
id: users
label: User migration
migration_group: mymodule_general_migration_groups
source:
  plugin: mymodule_migration_users
process:
  pass: user_password
  mail: user_email
  init: user_email
  status:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  name:
    plugin: dedupe_entity
    source: username
    entity_type: user
    field: name
    postfix: _
  created:
    plugin: callback
    source: created
    callable: strtotime
  changed: user_regdate
  access: user_regdate
  login: user_lastvisit
destination:
  plugin: entity:user
  md5_password: true
migration_dependencies: {}
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - mymodule_migration
```

Comment: Please try this first https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-destination-plugins-examples/migrating-users-advanced-password and if those do not work for you provide a more detailed explanation on which steps you have ran so far

Comment: Already went through this. It doesn't show how to decrypt md5 to plain text and convert them into hash. Do you get my point?

Comment: You cannot decrypt MD5 directly https://www.quora.com/Is-this-possible-to-decrypt-MD5 what you can is to reset all your users password and send a one-time-login password to them once they are migrated.

Comment: You mean there is no way to migrate md5 passwords to drupal hash?

Comment: I mean that you cannot obtain the original password (plain text) in order to re-hash it using your current mechanism. Typically you would do this https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-destination-plugins-examples/migrating-users but if this is not working for you as you metion in your comments, perhaps you could provide more information on why this does not works for you.

Comment: Yes, @d70rr3s is correct: Functions like `hash()` don't encrypt text, but calculate the hash value, and by definition they are one-way functions. (It means  there aren't inverse functions that from the hash return the original value.)

Comment: I found my solution over here https://www.aram.cz/article/rehash-md5-password-drupal-8

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about that - if Drupal would recognize an MD5 hash without any prefix. Maybe you should add the information you found to https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-destination-plugins-examples/migrating-users-advanced-password

Comment: I have updated my answer. And included a link to aram.cz/article/rehash-md5-password-drupal-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple code is working properly while migrating md5 password to drupal 8

```
$password_service = \Drupal::service('password');

  $password = $row->getSourceProperty('user_password'); // 'user_password' is the old db column which is in md5 format

  $hashed_password = 'U' . $password_service->hash($password); // U will indicate that the password needs rehashing.
  $row->setSourceProperty('hash_password', $hashed_password);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't know the password, only the hash, you can't migrate it directly. (MD5 is weak, but not that weak.) The whole purpose of hashing is that the password should be unknown to anyone except the user. There are 2 solutions to this.

- Reset all your users password and send a one-time-login password to them once they are migrated - as already suggested in the comments above.
- Write custom code that rehashes the password at login: "If the password is hashed with MD5, rehash it and store the hash when the user (successfully) logs in." This works because at login you have the user's password because they just entered it. And you know which hashing algorithm is used from the stored hash.Initially, you migrate the users with the MD5 password hash.

It turns out that Drupal does rehashing automatically (see [`UserAuth::authenticate()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserAuth.php/function/UserAuth%3A%3Aauthenticate/8.9.x)), but not for MD5 unless you modify the  [existing hash](https://www.aram.cz/article/rehash-md5-password-drupal-8) slightly by prefixing it with an "U". (Thanks, d70rr3s and  Souvik Das.) See also [user_update_7000](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.install/function/user_update_7000/7.x).

Comment: The second option could lead to security problems, since an attacker could try to login with a wrong password and get instant access. The first option is at the best if using this https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-destination-plugins-examples/migrating-users does not work for the use case.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no security problem. You of course validate the password before storing the rehashed password. If you provide the wrong password nothing happens.

Comment: You mean storing the old hashed password on another field, flagging the user so you you need to intervine the login process, that would be the way. That should be clarified in your answer. You could improve it with that example.

Comment: Isn't there any way to convert old site's md5 password to drupal hash password?
I dont want to rehash while login. All I want is, when I run `drush mim <migrate_id>`, all users will be migrated and convert md5 to hash

Comment: @d70rr3s: No, you don't need to flag anything. The hash itself reveals if it is a MD5 hash or hashed with Phpass - the current Drupal hashing algorithm. In other words, you migrate the MD5 hash as is, and then rehashes at login. Anyway, this is a lot more work than just resetting ... (Will update the answer slightly.)

Comment: @hansfn you are totally right if fact it seems is already supported by core, this the method used `\Drupal\user\UserAuth::authenticate` and checks if the password needs rehashing, so no further action is needed.

Comment: @d70rr3s Please check my answer. Found my solution.